# Is it possible to get coordinates of page relatively to Viewer control (DataDynamics.ActiveReports)?

Tags: c#, activereports

I have application under test with report preview. I want to click on control, which will be activated. For clicking on this control on report preview, I get coordinates of this control relatively to page. For getting coordinates of control I use CanvasItem.Bounds property and convert this coordinates to pixels. But how to get coordinates of page relatively to Viewer on which this page with controls is located? 
Or maybe somebody knows how to get CanvasItem coordinates relatively to Viewer control?

Thank you for any help!!!

Answer (score 0):

CanvasItem is an internal class and I would not recommend you to use it in your application. If you are simply looking to trap the click on a control then I think a better and simple approach would be to make use of TextBoxes with Hyperlink set. You can then handle the "Hyperlink" event of the viewer control to detect which control was clicked on the basis of its hyperlink value.

So I will list the steps:

1. Set Hyperlink property for the textboxes (say "a" for TextBox1 and "b" for TextBox2)
2. Capture the "Hyperlink" event of the viewer like this:

   ```
   private void viewer1_HyperLink(object sender, GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Viewer.Win.HyperLinkEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.HyperLink == "a")
       {
           MessageBox.Show("TextBox1 Clicked");
       }
       else
       {
           MessageBox.Show("TextBox2 Clicked");
       }
   }
   ```
3. Finally assign the report to the viewer:

   ```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       SectionReport1 rpt = new SectionReport1();
       viewer1.LoadDocument(rpt);
       viewer1.UseHyperlinkSettings = false;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue has already been replied on the C1Forums:
http://our.componentone.com/groups/topic/is-it-possible-to-get-coordinates-of-page-relatively-to-viewer-control-datadyna/

Regards,
Mohita